# Is For Honor cross platform / cross region?

Tags: for-honor

I did some research on the topic but I couldn't really find a clear answer to these questions (most articles I found were pre release debates about the topic):

**Can I play cross platform?** (PC/PS/XBOX)

and

**Can I play cross region?** (EU/NA/ASIA)

There's also the filter when searching for a match that changes from "your region" to "all regions" as soon as the matchmaking takes longer than usual. So what does "all regions" mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Faction wars (metagame) are cross platform, but the actual gameplay isn't.

You can play cross region, but as you have noticed it first searches in your region (EU for Europe, NA if you're in North America, etc.) before searching in all regions. Normally a game does this because it's easier to find and maintain a connection within the same region.

I'm fairly certain you could make it so it always searches across all regions, but someone will have to confirm that.